# Combine Excel tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to combine two excel tables(Table 1 & Table 2) to result as Table 3. New week column will be added every week with new data.
The Table 2 could be added to Table 1 or can be combined into a 3rd table. Any help will be appreciated.

Table1

```
Name    Task    Week 1
```

```
John    Task A   10
```

```
James   Task A   20
```

Table 2

```
Name    Task    Week 2
```

```
John    Task A   10
```

```
John    Task B   20
```

```
James   Task A   30
```

```
Ryan    Task A   40
```

Table 3

```
Name    Task    Week 1  Week 2
```

```
John    Task A   10      10
```

```
John    Task B           20
```

```
James   Task A   20      30
```

```
Ryan    Task A           40
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to have the appropriate cells/columns in Table 3 linked with their appropriate counterpart within Table 1 and/or 2. That way, when you populate the date within Table 1 and Table 2 it automatically populates the data in the appropriate cell within Table 3.

For example: In Table 1: If "John's Week 1, Task A, number of 10" is "C2" then in Table 3, you would put "=C2" in the cell that you want "John's Week 1, Task A, number of 10" to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many ways to do. I do similar things every month and I will do it in this way:

In my originally data, no column was there to store information of the datetime. (My data source doesn't provide this column.) The crucial step is to **manage your data before further processing**. What is missing from the data is the datetime information of every row of the tables.

Each week after you get get your three-column table, add a fourth column named Week and fill this column with the name of that week. (Not a must: rename your third column appropriately because its name should not change every week, and it makes little sense about what those numbers actually mean. I rename it Point.)

Table1

```
Name    Task    Point  Week
John    Task A   10    Week 1
James   Task A   20    Week 1
```

Table 2

```
Name    Task    Point  Week
John    Task A   10    Week 2
John    Task B   20    Week 2
James   Task A   30    Week 2
Ryan    Task A   40    Week 2
```

Then accumelate these four-column tables together:

```
Name    Task    Point  Week
John    Task A   10    Week 1
James   Task A   20    Week 1
John    Task A   10    Week 2
John    Task B   20    Week 2
James   Task A   30    Week 2
Ryan    Task A   40    Week 2
```

Actually you will just copy and paste the newest three-column to the bottom of the accumulated table and fill in the last column.  There's really no need to save a separate copy of a four-column table for each week.

I believe I can stop my answer here because the data after processing like it will be well-prepared enough for furthur use. (For example you can use a Pivot Table to summarize the accumulated table in the way you want. An alternative is to use SUMIFS, but you need to correctly populate the row headings and column headings manually.) The core of your problem is that **your original data was not yet ready**,  and you have to **get it better-prepared before using it**.